# Django: How to get a JSON object from models with ONLY fields and not pk and model key?

Tags: python, json, django

2 days with the same problem... 
overall, Django is very simple but for json, I do not understand...
I want to pass data from my database to be used in JS code in order to construct dynamically a table

first I tried to pass my data as a context trought a "data-" attribute in one of my html element
but the problem is that my data are in a string format instead of JSON and I am unable to parse

when I use django serializer to get an Json object, I have pk and model key that make it difficult to manipulate...

is there a easiest way to have a simple Json object from my model?

or, how is the good pratice to get data from server/database to be available in JS?

```
[
    {
        "pk": "4b678b301dfd8a4e0dad910de3ae245b",
        "model": "sessions.session",
        "fields": {
            "expire_date": "2013-01-16T08:16:59.844Z",
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

expected :

```
[
  {
     "expire_date": "2013-01-16T08:16:59.844Z",
     ...
  }
]
```

Comment: Django doesn't provide that functionality out of the box. You can use [**DRF's `Serializer`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) to get a more customized response structure.